# How can I use different colours for different groups of points in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

Consider the following `Dataset`:

```
ClearAll[tbl];
tbl = Dataset[{
    <|"a" -> "P", "x" -> 0.1, "y" -> 1.2|>,
    <|"a" -> "Q", "x" -> 0.1, "y" -> 1.75|>,
    <|"a" -> "R", "x" -> 0.2, "y" -> 0.67|>,
    <|"a" -> "P", "x" -> 0.3, "y" -> 2.22|>
}];
```

I can `ListPlot` columns `x` and `y`:

```
tbl // (Query[All, {"x", "y"}] /* ListPlot)
```

But I want the points to have three different colours based upon their values in the `a` column. It seems that `PlotMarkers` applies to the entire data set, not to individual points.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `tbl // Query[GroupBy["a"], All, {"x", "y"}] // ListPlot`?

Comment: As @kglr suggested but use `ListPlot[#, PlotMarkers -> Automatic] &` if you want different shapes as well as different colors.

Comment: @kglr Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tbl // Query[GroupBy["a"], All, {"x", "y"}] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Use `ListPlot[#, PlotMarkers -> Automatic] &` as suggested by Bob Hanlon in comments to get:

[image]

Alternatively, use `ListPlot[#, PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkers"] &` to get

[image]